# How to consume GraphQL Subscription with Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, graphql, subscription

I am creating a subscription with GraphQL, and I need to consume that subscription with Flutter, but I don't know how to do that, the thing that I need is something like a UI component that would be tied to a subscription and it will be automatically refreshed.

I will appreciate any feedback.

Comment: what library are you using ? did you try something already ?

Comment: I don't have used a library, I created like my own one, I created my API calls to GraphQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the next library https://github.com/zino-app/graphql-flutter

Comment: I was trying to use that library, but I don't know where I should initialize socketClient, could you give me any help?

Answer (score 9):

My GraphqlServer runs a subscription named `getLogs` which returns the log information in the following format.

```js
{
  "data": {
    "getLogs": {
      "timeStamp": "18:09:24",
      "logLevel": "DEBUG",
      "file": "logger.py",
      "function": "init",
      "line": "1",
      "message": "Hello from logger.py"
    }
  }
}
```

If you are like me who wants to use only the [GraphQL Client](https://github.com/zino-app/graphql-flutter/tree/master/packages/graphql) directly, then following sample could help.

```dart
import 'package:graphql/client.dart';
import 'package:graphql/internal.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class LogPuller extends StatefulWidget {
  static final WebSocketLink _webSocketLink = WebSocketLink(
    url: 'ws://localhost:8000/graphql/',
    config: SocketClientConfig(
      autoReconnect: true,
    ),
  );

  static final Link _link = _webSocketLink;

  @override
  _LogPullerState createState() => _LogPullerState();
}

class _LogPullerState extends State<LogPuller> {
  final GraphQLClient _client = GraphQLClient(
    link: LogPuller._link,
    cache: InMemoryCache(),
  );

  // the subscription query should be of the following format. Note how the 'GetMyLogs' is used as the operation name below.
  final String subscribeQuery = '''
    subscription GetMyLogs{
      getLogs{
        timeStamp
        logLevel
        file
        function
        line
        message
      }
    }
    ''';
  Operation operation;

  Stream<FetchResult> _logStream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // note operation name is important. If not provided the stream subscription fails after first pull.
    operation = Operation(document: subscribeQuery, operationName: 'GetMyLogs');
    _logStream = _client.subscribe(operation);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _logStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
            child: Container(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                strokeWidth: 1.0,
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: Text(
              snapshot.data.data['getLogs']
                  ['message'], // This will change according to you needs.
            ),
          );
        }
        return Container();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

As I am using a StreamBuilder to build the widget it will take care of closing the stream. If this is not the case for you, `stream.listen()` method will return a `StreamSubscription<FetchResult>` object which you can call the `cancel()` method which can be done inside `dispose()` method of a stateful widget or any such method for a standalone `Dart` client.

Answer (score 1):

Just find out the bug in this library, Just open the subscription.dart file by ctrl+click on Subscription. In that file, it is easy to see that socketClient variable is null. So just define it in initState() function as shown in the docs. Restart your app. And it works like a charm. So, basically, you just need to initialize that variable in the subscription.dart file.